# Reading text file not local directory

Tags: c#, text, streamreader

I have a text file that I would like to read into a rich text box. 
Everything is working fine but I am working off my USB pen and the text file is stored on that being the I:\ drive, stored in the programs debug folder. 
How could I make it so that no matter where I plug my USB in, and what the directory is called the program will read the file? 
I have got round it using my database by using a datasource but I don't know if there's such a thing for reading text files.

```
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"I:\filep\filep\bin\Debug\text.txt"))
```

Comment: Is having the file on usb a requirement?

Comment: you can't hardcode that because what happens if you have another folder mapped to `I` drive for example.. or how do you know that when you plug it in on a different machine or the same one for that matter that the drive letter will persist..?

Comment: @Izzy it is not a requirement, it is just what i have been working off

Comment: you need to do something like this before you can attempt to read from the StreamReader
`from driveInfo in DriveInfo.GetDrives() where driveInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Removal select driveInfo.RootDirectory.FullName` for example if you know `WMI` you could do it too.. there are several ways to do this

Comment: @MethodMan I may have phrased my question badly, I know that the drive letter will change from machine to machine when i plug in my usb with the file on, thats my problem. I have tried to use the google docs api to read it in but i cant seem to find a good tutorial or one that you can use a stream reader also. I am really stumped

Comment: @FlipperFlapper do an exact google search on the following 
`C# stackoverflow how to find USB Drive` there are tons of examples on the web

Comment: Given that the application is not on the same drive as the text file. I'd almost certainly prompt the user or use a configuration path for this. It'd be too error prone for my liking to try and find a file 5 folders deep on a random drive.

Comment: @MethodMan Thank you! I became fixated on the file itself rather than the drive, which was my main issue

Comment: You said `stored in the programs debug folder` is the program also stored there?

Comment: @JamesBarrass the program is also stored on the I:/ (usb) but it is a windows form application so the programs .exe file is stored in the debug folder

Comment: Could you not just use a relative path?

Comment: @JamesBarrass i have tried using a relative path but i am still getting errors on the absolute path as there will be no way of knowing the drive letter, well the way i have attempted anyway

Comment: But with a relative path you don't need to know the drive letter? The problem just disappears as long as you know the relative location.

Comment: @JamesBarrass I think i might have sorted it, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [iterating over your drives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives), checking

```
drive.Name + "filep\filep\bin\Debug\text.txt"
```

on each pass to [see if the file exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Edit from MethodMan's comment: if you know for sure your file lives on a thumb drive, you'll want this check in there as well

```
drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removal
```